# Why is this lat lng coordinate is split into 2 halfs?

Tags: gis

I have this file from tsp.gatech but the lat lng coordinate is divide into two half. Why is this?

```
COMMENT: Created July 7, 2012, www.tsp.gatech.edu/data/usa/
1 33613.158800 86118.306100
2 33100.954000 85529.675300
3 31571.835200 85250.489300
```

For example the first coordinate should be 33.613158800 86.118306100.

Update: I searched for New York City and I found it lat lng coordinate to be similar.

Update 2: I think it's incorrect formated see this image of points: http://www.tsp.gatech.edu/data/usa/img/usa115475_large.jpg. I get the points from a file from this website: http://www.tsp.gatech.edu/data/usa/index.html. The site is about a challenge and the file I downloaded is usa115475.tsp.

Comment: Are you sure it's lat/lon and not northing/easting? Either that, or it seems like the wrong datatype is being used, as the decimal point is way off.

Comment: Read my update. I searched the file for New York City.

Comment: It says edge weight is euklidian distance??? Maybe somethings wrong?

Answer (score 1):

[Euclidean Distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_distance) would tend to suggest the values are X,Y distances from a reference point (in feet, meters, kilometers, miles, ...). But this is normally reserved for small scale mapping where the effects of the curvature of the earth can be considered minor.

If the data seems to correspond to decimal degrees that are incorrectly formatted, there could be an error in whatever system is returning the data. But its better to review your own processes before pointing the finger. What query/process/code are you doing to obtain this data?

Comment: You're data set is entirely correct. Its been simplified from Lat/Lon to a 2D Euclidean Projection so that you can finish your homework without having to calculate effects of curvature of the earth. I suggest you spend a bit more time understanding the challenge (and looking for the many thousands of existing solutions online for this very problem using this exact data set). 

If you want to/need to re-complicate your problem, write a script to parse the data back into lat/lon format.

Comment: Do you want to say it's already projected to x,y pairs in cartesian system? Why did I found New York coordinate?

Comment: No. The data set is a simplification not a reprojection. In reality, two equidistant points in northern Canada are closer than two equidistant points in Florida. But this map simplification makes them equal which means you don't have to do any calculations that deal with the curvature of the earth.

You do not understand the problem you are trying to solve. The points could be any random set of X,Y points (like the initial Mona Lisa data set). This set simply started out life as a bunch of lat/lon but its entirely irrelevant to your challenge.

Comment: Maybe it's a language thing. Thank you anyway but I think you simply too much.

Comment: I've given you an explanation of why the data is correct, a suggestion for making that data back into Lat/Lon if you had to and direction to find sources that explain the problem and solutions in more depth. You've marked me down by 2 points. This is not elite thinking...